# How to set Content-Type for the multipart/form-data in node.js request

Tags: node.js, request, multipartform-data

Here is my request which is able to find the service but on the logs i am getting error saying content-type should be multipart/form-data, how should i set the content type in the following request.

```
    var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');


var formData = {
  // Pass a simple key-value pair 
  deviceId: '2612',
  // Pass data via Buffers 
  checksum: '132654798',
  fileSize: '60',
  fileType: 'configuration',
  compressionType: 'Z',
  // Pass data via Streams 
  file: fs.createReadStream('C:/Ruby193/Mybugs.txt'),
};



request.post({url:'https://transfer-upload-v1/file', formData: formData,}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I have read the answer at the same problem on Stack Overflow at this url [nodejs post multipart form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797670/nodejs-post-request-multipart-form-data)

It use the restler module!

Code sample from this url:

After some more research, I decided to use the restler module. It makes the multipart upload really easy.

```
fs.stat("image.jpg", function(err, stats) {
restler.post("http://posttestserver.com/post.php", {


       multipart: true,
        data: {
            "folder_id": "0",
            "filename": restler.file("image.jpg", null, stats.size, null, "image/jpg")
        }
    }).on("complete", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
  });
```